# OR Operator in an If Statement

Tags: javascript, operators

I've got two keys, `name` and `description`. Some have values, some don't and some are `undefined`.

I'm trying to write a catch-all if statement, but this doesn't seem to be working.

```
<% if (name && description || typeof name !== 'undefined' && typeof description !== 'undefined') { %>
  <h1><%= name %></h1>
  <h2><%= description %></h2>
<% } %>
```

If a `name` and `description` are defined, they render. If not, they don't render. If they're set to undefined however, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just replace or operator with and operator and will work fine

Comment: No need of last two conditions only use `(name && description)`

Comment: @Tushar I tried that, as I thought that statement would evaluate to `true` if `name` and `description` is not `undefined`, but it doesn't work. I'm using Parse, so I'm not sure if it's something to do with the way Parse stores it's `undefined` value.

Comment: @realph: http://jsfiddle.net/pac4bngz/ (note that there are no errors in the console) Well, this should work in this way. Are you sure that this error is related to the if line? can you please check twice?

Comment: @briosheje This is the line in the console that's causing the issue: `if (name && description) { ;` and this is the error that's being returned: `name is not defined`.

Comment: Then it has to be something to do with the parser itself. In Pure javascript this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your OR operator (||) to an AND operator (&&) to check that name and description are not equal to null before you try and use them with typeof.

If you don't need to check the typeof the variables and you are just checking that name and description are defined. You could simplify your code to:

```
<% if (name && description) { %>
  <h1><%= name %></h1>
  <h2><%= description %></h2>
<% } %>
```

Comment: This is the line in the console that's causing the issue: `if (name && description) { ;` and this is the error that's being returned: `name is not defined`.